# Rails 3: Return .XLS or .CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can I respond with a .xls file? Do I have to generate it myself or Rails does that for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails will not do that for you out of the box, but they are gems that can help you along the way.

I recommend: https://github.com/dasil003/csv_builder

This should make quick work of your requirement.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For generating xls files I suggest Spreadsheet https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet